# Unity Button List

Tags: list, function, unity-game-engine, button

Hey everyone I am trying to create a Button List in the parent of the buttons but when I wrote;

```
 public List<Button> buttonList;
```

I get an error how can I fix that ? I want to loop through my buttons and give them listener but like I said I can't write it this way and when I try to write it with GameObject instead of Button I can't onClick and Listener to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to import UI library from Unity Engine. At the top of your script you should add:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

Answer (score 0):

I added using UnityEngine.UI and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

replace

```
public List<Button> buttonList;
```

to

```
public List<Button> buttonList = new List<Button>();
```